# Powershell V2 vs V4 scoping differences

Tags: scope, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I am having a hard time with the literature on this.  I am hoping someone can explain the difference here so that I can better understand the flow of my scripts.

```
function select-bin {
    $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $objForm.Text = "Select a Bin"
    $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
    $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

    $x = @()

    # Create $OKButton and $objListBox ... removed code as not relevant.

    $OKButton.Add_Click({
        $x+=$objListBox.SelectedItems
        $objForm.Close()
    })

    $objForm.ShowDialog()
    if ($x) {
        return $x
    }
    else {
        return $null
    }
}
```

In the code sample above, it works great in Powershell V2, however in V4 the add_click section doesn't work.  It successfully closes the form (created in the functions scope) but fails to update $x.

So I guess here are my questions.

1. In V2, was the add_click section considered in the same scope as the function? (only way I see it having been able to update $x)
2. What is the proper way to have an event like this alter data?  I feel like declaring $x in the global scope is a bit much seeing as I only need it in the function.
3. In V4 what scope is add_click running in?  It is clearly different from what it was in V2, but is it running in the global?  is it relative to the $OKButton or the function?  I am assuming its a child of either the global or the function but I truly do not know.

Any clarity that anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated.  I have a lot of updating to do before my company moves to V4, seeing as I have not been following best practices for scoping (my bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V2, a ScriptBlock, when converted to a delegate, would run dot sourced in whatever scope happened to be the current scope.

Often, this was the scope that created the script block, so things worked naturally.  In some cases though, the scope it ran in had nothing to do with the scope it was created in.

In V4, these script blocks run in their own scope - a new scope that is the child of the current scope, just as they were a function and you called the function normally (not dot sourcing.)

I think your best bet is to use one of the following (in roughly best to worst):

- $script:x
- $x = Get-Variable -Scope 1 -Name x
- $global:x